# Obter X e Y da tela usando PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7

Eu quero criar um bot(macro) que execute algumas tarefas de click, para isso estou usando o **pyautogui** em **python**!

Porém não tenho muita experiencia em X e Y, e ficar testando isso manualmente e chato.

Eu gostaria, de obter o x e y clicando na tela, por exemplo, eu dou um click em tal local da tela e apresente no console o X e Y do local do click.
Possível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom uma forma de fazer isso em **pyautogui** seria basicamente assim:

```
#pega o retorno da posicao atual de x e y do mouse e passa o valor da tupla para as duas variaveis
x, y = pyautogui.position()
print "Posicao atual do mouse:"
print "x = "+str(x)+" y = "+str(y)

#retorna True se x & y estiverem dentro da tela
print "\nEsta dentro da tela?"
resp = pyautogui.onScreen(x, y)
print str(resp)
```

> Referência: [pyautogui](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html)

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução rápida usando [PyUserInput](https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput) e sem entrar em especificidades de sistema operacional: instâncias de `mouse` possuem o método `position()`, que retorna a posição (X, Y) a cada chamada:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput.git
```

```
>>> import pymouse
>>> mouse = pymouse.PyMouse()
>>> mouse.position()
(562, 528)
>>> mouse.position()
(1259, 195)
>>> mouse.position()
(157, 259)
```

Answer (score -2):

Fz muito tempo que voce perguntou mais editei o codigo acima para usuarios inicantes. So copiar e jogar no IDLE ou IDE.

codigo:

```
import pyautogui
import time
#pega o retorno da posicao atual de x e y do mouse e passa o valor da tupla para as duas variaveis
print('Posicione o MOUSE')
time.sleep(2)
x, y = pyautogui.position()
print ("Posicao atual do mouse:")
print ("x = "+str(x)+" y = "+str(y))

#retorna Truee se x & y estiverem dentro da tela
print ("\nEsta dentro da tela?")
resp = pyautogui.onScreen(x, y)
print (str(resp))
```

Comment: Não entendi a necessidade de copiar uma resposta apenas para adicionar um `print` e parênteses nos outros `print`s

Answer (score -2):

Copiei o primeiro código dos comentarios e coloquei dentro de um While:

import pyautogui

while True:
input('POSICIONE O MOUES E EM SEGUIDA TECLE ENTER: ')
#pega o retorno da posicao atual de x e y do mouse e passa o valor da tupla para as duas
x, y = pyautogui.position()
print( "Posicao atual do mouse:")
print("x = "+str(x)+" y = "+str(y))

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).